# How to use a div class to wrap some selected fields of a grid views view

Tags: views

I have came through this:

- [Views group different number of divs of a view by wrapping them](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/49838/views-group-different-number-of-divs-of-a-view-by-wrapping-them)
- [Views - Add a wrapper DIV around a Group](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/29840/views-add-a-wrapper-div-around-a-group)

but can't understand how to use a div class to wrap some selected fields of a grid views view. In my case, i want to wrap three fields of a view into a div class as the image shows below:
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by `div class`? Do you just mean a normal `div` tag?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's really simple by using the Field overwrites.

First, set the `(author) User: Picture` and `(author) User: Name` fields to "Exclude from display".

Then open the settings for `Content: Post date` field, and open "Rewrite results" fieldset.

Check "Rewrite output of this field". This will reveal another fieldset "Replacement Patterns" which should show you the tokens for all the fields above the current field. All you need to do is put a `<div>` wrapper in the textbox and copy the tokens you want in between the div tags.

[image]

Comment: Also check this post using the same method http://www.mediacurrent.com/blog/ultimate-markup-control-in-views

Comment: Perfect answer. Works for Drupal 10 as long as we use twig syntax, eg `{{ title }}` instead of `[title]`. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

you should use [hook_views_pre_render(&$views)](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7) or  theme_process_views_view_field()

```
function YOUR_THEME_preprocess_views_view_fields(&$vars) {

  if ($vars['view']->name == 'view_name') {

    foreach( $vars['view']->result as $key => $value) { 
      $add_start_div = '<div class="add_div">';
      $markup_for_field_name_1 = $value->field_name1[0]['rendered']['#markup'] ; 
      $value->field_name1[0]['rendered']['#markup'] = $add_start_div . $markup_for_field_name_1;
      $markup_for_field_name_3 = $value->field_name3[0]['rendered']['#markup'];
      $add_end_div = '</div>';
      $value->field_name3[0]['rendered']['#markup'] = $value->field_name3[0]['rendered']['#markup'] . $add_end_div;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: missing a couple of closing }}

Answer (score 2):

Create a template for rows style output for example: views-view-fields--frontpage-promoted-news-story--block.tpl.php . Look in views->advanced->themes for options. Copy and paste the name of the specificity of template you want and create a file with that name, then run 'rescan' so Drupal finds the new template.

Then do something like:

```
<?php
$field_vals = [];
foreach($fields as $id => $field){
    $field_vals[$id]= $field->content;
}
?>
<!-- layout fields -->
<div class="promoted-news-story">
<!-- image, title, date, body, link -->
    <div class="promoted-news-story__image-wrap">
        <?php print $field_vals['field_standard_header_image'];?>
    </div>
    <div class="promoted-news-story__content-wrap">
        <h2><?php print $field_vals['title'];?></h2>
        <?php print $field_vals['field_news_date'];?>
        <?php print $field_vals['body'];?>
        <?php print $field_vals['view_node'];?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Group some fields into views div ..
Please find this module ( Views fieldsets ):
https://www.drupal.org/project/views_fieldsets

[image: Views Fieldsets Module]